# let $ m,n \in \mathbb {N}$, $m <n$ , $A \in M _{ n \times m }(\mathbb{R})$, $B \in M_{m \times n}({\mathbb{R}})$. then

Tags: linear-algebra

Is  The following statement is  True/false  ?

let  $ m,n \in \mathbb {N}$, $m <n$ , $A \in M _{ n \times m }(\mathbb{R})$, $B \in M_{m \times n}({\mathbb{R}})$.

Then  Choose the correct option

$1)\:\operatorname{rank}(AB) = [\frac{m + n}{2}]$, the smallest integer  larger than  or  equal to $\frac{m+n}{2}$

$2)\:\operatorname{rank}(BA) = [\frac{m + n}{2}]$, the smallest integer  larger than  or  equal to $\frac{m+n}{2}$

My attempt  :  option $1)$  is True  and option $2$  is false

simply put $n =m$ ,then  $\operatorname{rank}(AB) =m$

$A = \begin{bmatrix}  1 &0 &0 \\ 0& 1&0  \end{bmatrix}\;$ and  $\;B = \begin{bmatrix}  1 &0 \\ 0& 1 \\0&0 \end{bmatrix}$. Then AB = I, that is $\operatorname{rank}(AB) = 2$

Is  my logic  is correct or not ?

Comment: What if both both $A, B$ are $0$? Also $n=m$ is only a special case of the statement.

Comment: Ranks AB = 0 ...@cansomeonehelpmeout

Comment: I agree, does that check out with your statement?